# java.lang.SecurityException: !@Too many alarms (500) registered from pid 10790 uid 10206

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm getting this error at the time of Schedule alarm using Alarm Manager

```
am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeMillis, pendingIntent);
```

Error is as follow

```
java.lang.SecurityException: !@Too many alarms (500) registered from pid 10790 uid 10206
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
at android.app.IAlarmManager$Stub$Proxy.set(IAlarmManager.java:206)
at android.app.AlarmManager.setImpl(AlarmManager.java:428)
at android.app.AlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.java:376)
```

Why this error is coming and how we can fix it.

Comment: Turns out this can also be caused by a [known issue on Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/185) that has been fixed in 10.0.0

Answer (score 46):

Unlike what the comment suggests, this might not be your fault. This started happening for us in production code somewhere mid March, this only happens on Samsung with Lollipop which only recently started to be rolled out.

Update:
This issue finally happened on one of the phones we have available.

like @goncalossilva said the problem is due to use of `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`, it seems that Samsung introduces a cap of 500 on the amount of alarms and no other vendor have this limit.

when creating a `PendingIntent` with `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` it will cancel the pending intent (obviously) won't cancel the alarm (also obvious), later if you cancel the alarm using the new pending intent it won't cancel the alarm (less obvious as `Intent.filterEquals` should be `true`). That being said, because the pending intent was canceled the old alarm won't actually fire, so there it no fear in introducing bugs by switching `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`.

regarding the need to restart the device after changing to `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, you don't have to restart you just need to wait for one of the alarms to fire so that you have a new slot for a new alarm.

you can try this code to reproduce the issue, then change to `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to see what happens.
you should also run `"adb shell dumpsys alarm"` to see all the generated alarms

```
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    for (int i = 0; i<1000; i++)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent("FOOFOOFOO");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

        long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000;
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstTime, pendingIntent);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Do you have any idea to fix it ?

Comment: This is also happening for us in production and started recently, without any changes on our part. Only Samsung devices and mostly (>95%) on Lollipop.

Comment: No, no idea how to fix this, not even sure there's an actual problem with the code.

Comment: We have tried explicitly cancelling a `PendingIntent` before scheduling it in `AlarmManager`, to no avail. Fixing this is not going to be pleasant :/

Comment: I'm also seeing this for a production app.  It's happening on a Samsung SM-G925V running 5.0.2.  I didn't make any changes to this code either.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm start getting 40+ reports for this error. Galaxy S4 (ja3g) is on the Top. Please help..

Comment: Using `adb shell dumpsys alarm` I found out that our app had been leaking alarms all along, it just wasn't visible before this. Changing FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT to FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT and making sure the PendingIntents were identical (extracting their creation to a common method) solved it for us.

Comment: same thing for samsung devices on android 5 and 6.

Comment: Any news on this issue?

Comment: I would like to take this opportunity to thank Samsung for making us developers' lives easier and simpler. Thank you!

Comment: Any news about this? I have also this problem but I use and used UPDATE_CURRENT all the time.

Comment: For some reason this sample code to reproduce the crash did not work for me. But I've created similar simple test using our codebase: created 300 alarms (it went ok), cancelled all these 300, then tried to create 300 more - and there was a crash. Do not use `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` to cancel your alarms, this is not working on Samsung devices

Answer (score 6):

For those encountering this problem solely on Samsung devices running Lollipop, you are probably using `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` with your `PendingIntent`s. Switch to `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` (making any other adjustments, if necessary), and the problem should go away.

My completely unfounded guess is that Samsung is doing some "optimizations" with `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` where they don’t remove the canceled `PendingIntent` right away but only mark it for deletion and then do it too infrequently (or not at all?).

**Edit**

We've found that devices where this problem occurs will be in a broken state (filled with `PendingIntent`s?) until they are restarted or the app is reinstalled.

Comment: I use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT and it also occurs.

Comment: @Zenco did your users reinstall your app or rebooted their phones? That seemed to do the trick for us after this change.

Comment: Ok Thank you. No they didnt reinstalled the app or reboot the device. I use now a try catch block as a another workaround without reboot ;)

Comment: I'm seeing the same but even when using FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT. On a nexus device dumping the alarms shows I have no more than 2 at any time but on samsung devices at crash time there's 500. I'm trying to investigate with a user if not using the "window" parameter may help as I currently use that for one alarm at 300ms and another at 1000ms and it's the 1000ms alarm that doesn't clear.

Answer (score 4):

**Never** use FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT with PendingIntents that you use when setting alarms. If you want to reschedule the alarm for a different time you don't need any flag at all; just create a duplicate PendingIntent with flags of zero and then use it to set() an alarm: this will implicitly cancel the existing alarm and then set it for the newly-specified time. If you used FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT when you created the new PendingIntent, though, it breaks the Alarm Manager's ability to recognize that it's "the same" as the now-canceled PendingIntent, and you wind up with the old one hanging around, undeliverable, taking up memory and CPU. I've seen apps with this bug rack up literally hundreds of stale alarms in the system, enough to be a noticeable performance and memory-usage hit.

If you just want to change the extras without actually rescheduling the existing alarm, that is what FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT is for. If you just want to reschedule or cancel the alarm, just use 0 for the flags.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the newest Lollipop build on Samsung devices restricts the number of alarms you can register. I've temporarily fixed the problem in my app by only registering at most X alarms at any given time (I've arbitrarily chosen X = 50 but judging by the error message I believe you can go up to 499. I have not tested this however).

I've released a version with this temporary fix a week ago and I haven't had this crash reported since.

Comment: Assume if my app shows around 6 notifications each day. Does that mean after around 3 months my app will crash? Or it is the limitation means, in a day phone can manage around 500 notification overall.

Answer (score 0):

For me changing to `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` alone did not help to get rid of the multiple entries of my pendingIntents (watched with `adb shell dumpsys alarm > dump.txt`).

I fixed it by changing the way I cancel those pending intents from

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel();
```

to

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel();
alarmManager.cancel(pi);
```

This was necessary for `.getBroadcast()` and `.getService()`. Interestingly with `.getActivity()` it was not. Sadly I have no clue why this is the case.

All on a Samsung Galaxy S4 with Android 5.0.1. Perhaps this helps someone else, too.

Comment: Calling cancel() on a PendingIntent instance is exactly like using FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT.  That's why you were still leaking the old alarms.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it using the flag: PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
    MainActivity.this, 200, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);

am.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, realtime + 2000, pendingIntent);
```

I tested it into a Galaxy S4 running in Android 5.0.1.