# TaskStackBuilder in PendingIntent not working

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications, back-stack

I am trying to recreate a back stack for the Activity on notification pressed with this code:

```
Intent firstIntent = new Intent(this, First.class);  
Intent secondIntent = new Intent(this, Second.class);    
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

 stackBuilder.addNextIntent(firstIntent);
 stackBuilder.addNextIntent(secondIntent);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 
 Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

 NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                    .setContentTitle(fromName)
                                    .setContentText(message)
                                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

  NotificationManager notificationManager =
                                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

  notificationManager.notify(0 ,notificationBuilder.build());
```

but it doesn't work. When I press the notification the Second activity is opened but pressing the back button, the activity is finished while I want to go back to First activity.

Setting parentActivityName in the AndroidManifest doesn't work.

What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is the _minSdkVersion_ in your build.gradle?

Answer (score 10):

Try changing

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
```

to

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Can you please explain why this worked?

Comment: @SaketJain: No idea to be honest. I was facing the same issue and came across some SO answer (not able to find it now) which suggested to use FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT flag instead of FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT which turned out to be working fine for me. It's more of a workaround than a proper solution because on [some Samsung devices using Lollipop FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT flag throws crash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344971/java-lang-securityexception-too-many-alarms-500-registered-from-pid-10790-u). I will update my answer if I ever find some good solution to this problem with proper explanation.

Comment: Thanks. I have currently implemented it using the CANCEL flag, however, I would actually prefer a better approach as well. Let's keep looking :)

Comment: i tried this but really it made no difference on my app in android API 22,maybe it made a difference to other guys. i do highly suggest consulting the official docs on this as it helped to to resolve the same problem

Comment: @GaneshMohan Thanks it worked. Just wanted to know is this the right approach?