# android limit of notifications in alarm manager

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, alarm

at the moment i set notification and show this with delay. for that i use the alarm manger.

my question is:
is there an limit of of maximum notifications and / or maximum alarms?

i develope apps for iOS and there is a maximum numbers of 68 notifications.
is this case with android the same?

Comment: I have not found any documentation about the size limit, but not sure if there is a max. I know I left my phone home one day, and when I got home that night, there was several hundred tweets, bunch of FB notifications, e-mails from all my accounts, and some other random notifications about app upgrades. It consolidates them into a single number along the left side to make them all fit. I can't imagine letting it go long enough to see it hit a max limit. For you to test, you can make a loop with an indetermined number of notitications.

Comment: I don't know if you want to do it, but  i think, this is not a best practice and its not good for users, if you are trying to show a lot of notification, for this you can accumulate the number of notifications that phone received in one notification or upddating the current notification .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Alarm notifications, and based on my experience, Samsung devices have a limit of 500 scheduded alarms (no matter if I cancel the alarms or set the flag FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT).

I don't found this limit on Nexus or other android manufacturer.

More info:
[java.lang.SecurityException: !@Too many alarms (500) registered from pid 10790 uid 10206](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344971/java-lang-securityexception-too-many-alarms-500-registered-from-pid-10790-u)

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException extends RuntimeException, so the caller of the method that sets an alarm is not aware of it, so the application can crash at any moment being a complete failure without the user or even the programmer being able to know the reason. Very bad, Samsung. Nasty programming practice. Even an student at first course knows that RuntimeException's are only for programming errrors producing runtime problems, not for conditions that can happen under normal operation.