# Security exception of 500 alarms limit on Samsung

Tags: android

Anyone is facing the 500 alarms limit exception on Samsung devices. I searched for hours and I can find only 2 posts about (one in stack overflow). But it does not seem to solve the problem.

I am creating alarms using pendingIntent generated from flag_update_current .

When I cancel the alarm,I generate the same intent but with flag_cancel_current

I am seeing this security exception of 500 alarms. What should I do? How can I fix it for users who are seeing it already

Thanks

Comment: Why would you be setting 500 alarms?

Comment: There are situations where the user may have too many alarms spread across a year. Plus I am not sure if slot is being emptied when the alarm is cancelled

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344971/java-lang-securityexception-too-many-alarms-500-registered-from-pid-10790-u

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to not set 500+ alarms. Instead, set only the next alarm and when that alarm fires in addition to doing whatever you are currently doing, set the next alarm. This ensures that all alarms fire at the appropriate time, but keeps the number of concurrent alarms minimized.

Comment: Thats a good suggestion for sure. The problem  that this will result in quering database up on every alarm and could be intensive. Also, if something wrong happens and one is alarm is missed for any reason then thats it for the alarms. The impact is high

Comment: Btw, I will wait for more answer or suggestions. If not then this would be the accepted answer

Comment: Getting the same exception in Work Manager as well