# Firebase Messaging - "too many alarms" on Samsung's Android devices

Tags: java, android, firebase, samsung-mobile, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are using Firebase Messaging in Android app and since last week we reported many crashes from Samsung devices. **The problem is not related with any of our classes**. We are not using AlarmManager etc.

Here are the stacktraces:

1) Parcel.java

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: !@Too many alarms (500) registered from pid 13776 uid 10011
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
   at android.app.IAlarmManager$Stub$Proxy.set(IAlarmManager.java:206)
   at android.app.AlarmManager.setImpl(AlarmManager.java:428)
   at android.app.AlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.java:215)
   at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzah(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzag(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzag(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzm(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

2) In Binder.java

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } in com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService$1@12533ba
   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:891)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure from system
   at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:772)
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:396)
   at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService$1.onReceive(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:881)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by android.os.DeadObjectException
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Binder.java)
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:3075)
   at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:767)
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:396)
   at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService$1.onReceive(Unknown Source)
   at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:881)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Do you have similar problems? Do you know what could be a potential problem?
I'm using firebase@9.6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news! With the [last update 10.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#10.0) the firebase team solved the problems with *Too many alarms* in Samsung devices, this is the patch note:

> **Fixed** - An issue that caused extra alarms to be incorrectly set, resulting in crashes with Too Many Alarms in the stack trace on some Samsung devices.

Good programming!

Comment: That's sounds great! Thanks for the info! :)

Comment: I'm using firebase 11.4.2 and still getting the crash, here is the log 
[crash](https://gist.github.com/tamtom/743adb781cc9af7bc79b8ee981d22c72)