# Security Exception is crashing my android app

Tags: android, firebase

from my Google Developer Account i am getting crash report. In my crash report i am getting the below exceptions.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1693)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1646)
  at android.app.IAlarmManager$Stub$Proxy.set(IAlarmManager.java:228)
  at android.app.AlarmManager.setImpl(AlarmManager.java:734)
  at android.app.AlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.java:390)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzagc(Unknown Source:0)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzd(Unknown Source:0)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zza(Unknown Source:0)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzm(Unknown Source:0)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run(Unknown Source:0)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
```

Please, someone help me to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Please share some of you code, otherwise we have no way of helping you

Comment: Refer this link once, you may get an idea. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40677915/4862479    and    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344971/java-lang-securityexception-too-many-alarms-500-registered-from-pid-10790-u

Comment: @KailasBhakade Thank you for your reply. Now can i  downgrade to 9.4.0 or Upgrade to 10.0 or higher.