# IllegalStateException AlarmManager Maximum limit of concurrent alarms 500 reached on Android 10

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-10.0

Using alarms with pending broadcasts, this was working as intended until recently a crash started appearing for
**RealMe devices running on Android 10** and few **OPPO devices running on Android 7.1.1**

Crash :
`IllegalStateException: Maximum limit of concurrent alarms 500 reached for uid on AlarmManager.setRepeating()`

StackTrace :

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Maximum limit of concurrent alarms 500 reached for uid: u0a336, callingPackage: com.example.your.app
       at android.os.Parcel.createException + 2095(Parcel.java:2095)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException + 2055(Parcel.java:2055)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException + 2003(Parcel.java:2003)
       at android.app.IAlarmManager$Stub$Proxy.set + 320(IAlarmManager.java:320)
       at android.app.AlarmManager.setImpl + 709(AlarmManager.java:709)
       at android.app.AlarmManager.setRepeating + 454(AlarmManager.java:454)
```

Setting alarm by using :

```
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        applicationContext, 0,
                        Intent(applicationContext, MyBroadcastReceiver::class.java),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT )

alarmManager.setRepeating(
                AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                INITIAL_DELAY,
                ONE_MINUTE_MILLIS,
                pendingIntent )
```

Also tried :

```
alarmManager.setExact(
                AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                INITIAL_DELAY,
                pendingIntent )
```

Also tried with and without :

1. Flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`
2. Cancelling the alarm before setting
3. Cancelling the pending intent before setting

Is this device and android version specific crash (98% on RealMe Android 10 devices), or is there anything i am missing here that could prevent this crash to occur ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344971/java-lang-securityexception-too-many-alarms-500-registered-from-pid-10790-u

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.SecurityException: !@Too many alarms (500) registered from pid 10790 uid 10206](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344971/java-lang-securityexception-too-many-alarms-500-registered-from-pid-10790-u)

Comment: I'm having similar issue (Oppo devices with Android 7.1.1 & TCL devices with Android 10). The Android source code that throws this exception is here (line 1762): https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/AlarmManagerService.java

Comment: Did you find  any solution ? Please post answer (if any)

Comment: I'm looking for a solution too. have you figured out any approach? Thanks!