# Delete specific ALARM from AlarmManger in Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am building a reminder app using alarmManger but I don't know how to delete a specific alarm.

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
```

The Receiver is a normal and simple Receiver.

My problem is that I want to edit/remove an alarm that has been added.
I know conceptually how to [remove an alarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963271/android-alarmmanager-problem-with-setting-resetting-an-alarm/5055517#5055517), but I can't remove a specific alarm in alarmManger when several have been added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by Id that you set in alarm manager you can access specific alarm, in your code:

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
```

at this line choose **ID** separate from each other , then you can get specific alarm by it's id

```
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), ID, intent, 0);
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Thank you very much :).How can i set different ID and get the ID for different alarms?

Comment: you can keep ids in database when you create a new alarm and then edit or delete it by its id

Comment: and how can i set the id?i can not just throw a number

Comment: you can use System.currentTimeMillis() as ID and store it in your database

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542099/cant-stop-the-ringing-alarm-from-another-activity#51542099 @MHP

Answer (score 3):

You have to set unique requestCode for the PendingIntent :

to set:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext,
            11111, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

to cancel :

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext,
            11111, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Thank you very much :).How can i set different ID and get the ID for different alarms?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an unique id (`requestCode`), specific to the alarm you want to cancel. I've called that id `customId`. Pass that id to your intent (rather than passing 0 as you currently do).

```
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), customId, intent, 0);
```

store customId however you want but you can later get the alarm using the flag `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`:

```
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), customId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

And then you can do what you want to `alarmIntent`. In your code your Alarm Manager is called `manager` so you would call:

```
manager.cancel(alarmIntent);
```

Comment: I have tried above, setting alarm is working and also shows notification but deleting causes all alarms to delete. I have checked by break point debugging that my list's items values are always unique wrt position. [gist here](https://gist.github.com/talhahasanzia/42a3e9ef0fa239cda06511a9571c18b3)
Kindly have a look at my methods.

Answer (score 1):

When canceling the AlarmManager do not use a PendingIntent with a flag of FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT. Instead, cancel the PendingIntent explicitly after canceling the alarm:

```
am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);
am.cancel(p); p.cancel();`
```

Comment: Actually, it's not needed to call `p.cancel()`.  All you need is `am.cancel(p)`.  Also, using `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`, or not, is strictly for updating or removing the Intent extras associated with the PendingIntent.  See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029400/flag-cancel-current-or-flag-update-current/14036621#14036621

Comment: yup, PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, alert.idAlert, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT

Comment: That being said, if you create an alarm with a PendingIntent that uses `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`, you have to use it again when cancelling the alarm.

Comment: *Never* use FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT when working with PendingIntents that are used by alarms.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029400/flag-cancel-current-or-flag-update-current/39926854#39926854 for more details.

Comment: I have tried above, setting alarm is working and also shows notification but deleting causes all alarms to delete. I have checked by break point debugging that my list's items values are always unique wrt position.  I have also tried adding `p.cancel();`
[gist here](https://gist.github.com/talhahasanzia/42a3e9ef0fa239cda06511a9571c18b3)
Kindly have a look at my methods.

Answer (score 0):

That's simple.Just give a specific request code on creating on creating pending intent for each alarm.like
 PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), your specific code e.g 1001, intent, 0);

and when you want to delete the alarm just create a pending intent with that specific code and cancel it.
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), your specific code e.g 1001, intent, 0);
alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much :).How can i set different ID and get the ID for different alarms?

Comment: U Welcome.If you are setting multiple alarms then set those alarms in a loop and use the counter of loop as request code in pending intent.and when you want to remove then use the same logic.again start a loop.and use the counter as request code in pending intent.But take care of one thing that the logic should be same at both time.