# Query about FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT Usage in AlarmManager

Tags: android

I've been exploring the use of `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` in setting up and cancelling alarms with Android's `AlarmManager`. There are various opinions regarding the use of this flag, as seen in these discussions:

[java.lang.SecurityException: !@Too many alarms (500) registered from pid 10790 uid 10206](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29344971/java-lang-securityexception-too-many-alarms-500-registered-from-pid-10790-u)

[FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT or FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029400/flag-cancel-current-or-flag-update-current)

However, my tests haven't shown any adverse effects. I'm using the following code to set a midnight alarm, which is executed at app startup. The code first cancels any existing alarm before setting a new one:

```
private static void uninstallMidnightBroadcastReceiver() {
    Context context = MyApplication.instance();
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MidnightBroadcastReceiver.class);

    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            0,
            intent,
            embedFlagMutable(PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
    );

    try {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    } catch (java.lang.RuntimeException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
        trackEvent("uninstallMidnightBroadcastReceiver", "fatal", e.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void installMidnightBroadcastReceiver() {
    uninstallMidnightBroadcastReceiver();

    Context context =MyApplication.instance();
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MidnightBroadcastReceiver.class);

    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            0,
            intent,
            embedFlagMutable(PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
    );

    try {
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
                RTC_WAKEUP,
                toTimestamp(atNextStartOfDay(System.currentTimeMillis())),
                TWENTY_FOUR_HOURS,
                pendingIntent
        );
        trackEvent("installMidnightBroadcastReceiver", "success", null);
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException | java.lang.IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
        trackEvent("installMidnightBroadcastReceiver", "fatal", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

After starting and stopping the app multiple times, I checked the number of alarms installed in the system using `adb shell dumpsys alarm`. My observations indicate that only one midnight alarm is installed, implying that previous alarms are being cancelled properly.

Despite this, I'm curious about the potential side effects of using `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` for both alarm setup and cancellation.

Could there be scenarios or specific conditions under which using this flag might not be ideal? I would appreciate any insights or experiences you might have on this matter.

Thank you!